# How would I create a rotation matrix that rotates X by a, Y by b, and Z by c?

Tags: java, math, geometry, ardor3d

How would I create a rotation matrix that rotates X by a, Y by b, and Z by c?

I need to formulas, unless you're using the ardor3d api's functions/methods.

Matrix is set up like this

```
xx, xy, xz,
yx, yy, yz,
zx, zy, zz
```

A Quaternion is fine too.

Comment: This is not meaningful; the result is different depending on what order you do the rotations in.

Comment: Do you mean, rotate around the X-axis by a, etc.?

Comment: Again this is probably better on Mathematics: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Three_dimensions). It gives separate matrices for each axis of rotation. But `X*(Y*(Z*v)))` is of course equal to `(X*Y*Z)*v`, so you can get a single rotation matrix R as `R=X*Y*Z`.

Comment: Keep in mind that rotation matrices don't commute, so order matters.  In other words, X*Y*Z != Z*Y*X

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
glrotate(c, 0, 0, 1); // with respect to Z axis
glrotate(b, 0, 1, 0); // with respect to Y axis
glrotate(a, 1, 0, 0); // with respect to X axis
```